# Accessibility Magnifier for application

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, accessibility

I would like to create an feature for our app where elderly people can enable magnifier and this feature magnifies views present inside the application.

Currently on all latest android device already have magnifier inside the accessibility mode.

Questions :

1. Do we have any possibilities to access magnifier from accessibility?
   Ref : (https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/window-magnifier)
2. Do we have solution to apply in all views inside our activity or fragments layout files.
   Ref : (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/magnifier)

I tried second approach and it works but issue is that we have to apply on each and every views inside the layout file, is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: It's usually better to **not** try to have an accessibility feature, such as a magnifier, built into *just your app*. When a user takes advantage of an OS provided accessibility feature, they can use that feature on *any app*, not just yours.